# How to use foreach loop in this case

Tags: php

I tried using foreach loop instead of while and it throws an error. I don't understand the problem why it isn't working in this case. Please someone help me in using foreach instead of while in the code below:

`Foreach: tried but throwing errors`

```html
 $r=$mysqli->query("SELECT * from category");
                $row=$r->fetch_assoc();
                foreach($row as $cat)
                {?>
                    <tr class = "gradeX">
                      <td><?php echo $cat['cid'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $cat['name'] ?></td>
                      <td><div class = "center"><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary btn-mini">Edit</a> <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></div></td>
                      </tr>
                  <?php }?>
```

`While: Works perfectly`

```html
<?php
                $r=$mysqli->query("SELECT * from category");
                
                while($row=$r->fetch_assoc())
                {?>
                    <tr class = "gradeX">
                      <td><?php echo $row['cid'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                      <td><div class = "center"><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary btn-mini">Edit</a> <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></div></td>
                      </tr>
                  <?php }?>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Error: `Illegal string offset 'cid' `

Comment: try `foreach( $r->fetch_assoc() as $cat ){...}`

Comment: @RamRaider Still getting the error.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe you should all some print statements and see the content of row\

Comment: `$row=$r->fetch_assoc(); foreach($row ...)` fetches a single row `while($row=$r->fetch_assoc())` fetches a row on each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at your code:

```
$row=$r->fetch_assoc();
foreach($row as $cat)
```

Here you fetch a single row and then loop over it, so your `$cat` is the value of the fields in that row.  Not the next row.

So it's no surprise when you do this

```
  <td><?php echo $cat['cid'] ?></td>
```

And `$cat = 'foo'` *(will have to imagine foo is the value of the `cid` column in the row, `$row['cid'] = 'foo'`)* that you get the error you are seeing.

> Error: Illegal string offset 'cid'

We can easily test this:

```
//if we agree this is a simplified way of doing what you are doing
<?php
    /*
       $row = $r->fetch_assoc();  //['cid' => 'foo']
       $cat = $row['cid']; //from foreach loop on $row
    */

     $cat = 'foo'
?>

<td><?php echo $cat['cid'] ?></td>
```

Output

```
<td><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cid' in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
f</td>
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7aaad30f158c8b2607dce5225aebdb1a66e9d35d)

When you do

```
    while($row=$r->fetch_assoc())
```

The value of `$row` changes on each iteration, to the next row.  Using while to loop over the DB results is the expected way to do it.  Unless you fetch all the results and then loop over them, but in some cases that's less efficient.

Hope that helps it make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible method to allow the use of `foreach` to iterate through the recordset as above would be to use a `generator` type function that `yields` the row object which can then be iterated through. A simple example, using a `mysqli` connection:

```
function pre($data){/* only for display purposes */
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($data,true) );
}

function getrs( $obj ){/* the generator function that "yields" the row object */
    for( $i=0; $i < $obj->num_rows; $i++ )yield $obj->fetch_assoc();
}


$sql='select * from sport order by rand() limit 100';
$res=$db->query( $sql );
foreach( getrs( $res ) as $rs )pre( $rs );
```

More info on [Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting another method. Appreciate your help.